# C++ and table format printing

Tags: c++

I am looking for how to print in C++ so that table column width is fixed.
currently I have done using spaces and `|` and `-`, but as soon as number goes to double digit all the alignment goes bad.

```
|---------|------------|-----------|
| NODE    |   ORDER    |   PARENT  |
|---------|------------|-----------|
|  0      |     0      |           |
|---------|------------|-----------|
|  1      |     7      |     7     |
|---------|------------|-----------|
|  2      |     1      |     0     |
|---------|------------|-----------|
|  3      |     5      |     5     |
|---------|------------|-----------|
|  4      |     3      |     6     |
|---------|------------|-----------|
|  5      |     4      |     4     |
|---------|------------|-----------|
|  6      |     2      |     2     |
|---------|------------|-----------|
|  7      |     6      |     4     |
|---------|------------|-----------|
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to define a default width for your printing format.  Can you show us how you are printing.  `std::cout` or `printf()`

Comment: See my solution here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/20924887/1325279](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20924887/1325279)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) manipulator for cout.

There's also a [`std::setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) to specify the filler, but it defaults to spaces.

If you want to center the values, you'll have to do a bit of calculations. I'd suggest right aligning the values because they are numbers (and it's easier).

`cout << '|' << setw(10) << value << '|' << setw(10) << value2 << '|' << endl;`

Don't forget to include `<iomanip>`.

It wouldn't be much trouble to wrap this into a general table formatter function, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: @Avinash: "What's wrong with this" isn't really a good question. Are you getting a compilation error? Is it formatted wrong? Please provide more. You can update your question with this...

Comment: During parallel / multicore programs, this will get screwed up for sure.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [beautiful `printf()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). I find it easier & nicer for formatting than `cout`.

Examples:

```
int main()
{
    printf ("Right align: %7d:)\n", 5);
    printf ("Left align : %-7d:)\n", 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avinash's comment to the accepted solution nicely highlights precisely why printf() is far superior to cout for formatted output. ;)

Comment: @dandan78 Which comment? :D

Comment: I completely agree that `printf` is far more convenient than all that `cout` torture. .NET's `Format` isn't much better, and Java's `print/prinln` a catastrophy. I could regret good old `print using` in Basic.

Answer (score 3):

Might as well give the [**C++20 `std::format`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75024429/2706707) answer, since we already have the [C++ `std::cout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3867152/2706707) and [C `printf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3867279/2706707) answers.

```
std::cout << std::format( "|{:^9}|{:^9}|{:^9}|\n", node, order, parent );
```

OP, your column widths are all different sizes. Here I made them all 9. Also, horizontal lines don’t really increase legibility, but they use up a lot of space. I would personally get rid of them.

```
| NODE    | ORDER   | PARENT  |
|   11    |    7    |    3    |
|   12    |    5    |   11    |
```

Formatting stuff this way is really easy with `std::format`. Be sure to check out [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter).

Oh yeah, don’t forget to:

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
```