# How to pad strings with spaces up to a certain limit?

Tags: c++, whitespace, padding

I have a string `s`, and I need it to pad up right side of the string with spaces, up to 15 chars. I tried using `setw()`, but that just adds 15 spaces regardless.

So if `s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"` (15 chars), no white space should be added.

If `s = "aaa"`, then 12 white space characters should be added.

Is there a function for this in `iomanip`?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: its just how I have to output my program. It's just a formatting thing when using cout

Comment: Sounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765155/how-can-i-easily-format-my-data-table-in-c) is really what you want.

Comment: _"Is there a function for this in iomanip?"_ Just look up [`std::ios_base::width`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width).

Comment: @NathanOliver For those also curious, [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) as well as [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and [90% of the battle is won when we solve the XY Problem in Product Management](https://medium.com/swlh/90-of-the-battle-is-won-when-we-solve-the-xy-problem-in-product-management-5a7aef1fa4fa).

Answer (score 0):

`<iomanip>` includes `std::setw`, which is right-justified by default, but `std::left` is available too:

```
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(15) << "foo" << "bar";
```

Output:

```
foo            bar
```

Observe that `std::left << std::setw()` is required before each output that you want to have padded.