# How can this print function be formatted properly?

Tags: c++

When my print function is called multiple times, the formatting of the list being printed gets changed.

I've tried researching ways to use the setw and other ostream modifiers, but cannot find the issue that is causing the list to be changed after the first iteration.

Here is the function I am using to print my arrays:

```
void printArray(Car array[], int n)
{
    cout << "Make" << setw(10) << "Model" << setw(13) << "Horsepower"
         << setw(8) << "Price\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(12) << left << array[i].make << setw(12) << left 
             << array[i].model << setw(6) << left <<  array[i].horsepower 
             << setw(9) << left <<  array[i].price;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I was expecting the function to print something like this every iteration:

```
Make        Model   Horsepower Price

Lamborghini Diablo      550   290000
Honda       Civic       180   9000
Chevy       Silverado   300   30000
```

And here is the output that I get:

```
Make     Model   Horsepower Price

Lamborghini Diablo      550   290000
Honda       Civic       180   9000
Chevy       Silverado   300   30000


Sorted (ascending) by price:

MakeModel     Horsepower   Price

 Honda       Civic       180   9000
Chevy       Silverado   300   30000
Lamborghini Diablo      550   290000


Sorted (descending) by horsepower:

MakeModel     Horsepower   Price

 Lamborghini Diablo      550   290000
Chevy       Silverado   300   30000
Honda       Civic       180   9000
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20924887/6059586) should help you.

Comment: should use `setw` first for your headers, e.g. `cout << setw(10) << "Make" ...`

Comment: Would you know any reason for the "Make" and "Model" to become attached after the first iteration?

Comment: @Stanky-kun because no width is set for your first cout and since the first header is right aligned it looks as if there's setw in place

Comment: @Arne Awesome, thank you for the help.

Comment: BTW, you should consider `right` allignment for the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the constant width using setw() method

```
Eg.
cout<<setw(20)<<"text";
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, your first field was not set by `setw`, another thing to note is the use of `endl` instead of `\n` in the headers.

**What you should be doing**

```
void printArray(Car array[], int n)
{
    cout << left << setw(12) << "Make" << setw(10) << "Model" << setw(13) << "Horsepower"
         << setw(10) << "Price" << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(12) << left << array[i].make << setw(12) << left 
             << array[i].model << setw(6) << left <<  array[i].horsepower 
             << setw(9) << left <<  array[i].price;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```