# Setw not seeming to work consistently in output file

Tags: c++, formatting, setw

The program I'm building is meant to output students names, their 5 scores, and their grade from a input file named "students.txt" into an output file named "output.txt". All of the calculation required is correct, but the formatting of the output file is not, as I want all of the scores and grades to be aligned under their titles. I was under the impression that setw included within it the text it's applied to, but it seems to be applied inconsistently in the same file, to my knowledge. I know that the problem lies with the differing lengths of the names being used, I just don't know how to solve that, as I thought setw was supposed to be used for formatting in that circumstance. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

struct studentType
{
    int scores[5];
    string fName;
    string lName;
    char grade;
};

void read(ifstream& inFile, studentType students[], int numStudents);

void calcGrade(studentType students[], int numStudents);

void print(ofstream& outFile, studentType students[], int numStudents);

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    const int numStudents = 12;

    studentType students[20];

    inFile.open("students.txt");
    outFile.open("output.txt");

    read(inFile, students, numStudents);

    calcGrade(students, numStudents);

    print(outFile, students, numStudents);

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();


    return 0;
}

void read(ifstream& inFile, studentType students[], int numStudents)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        inFile >> students[i].fName >> students[i].lName;
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 5; i2++)
            inFile >> students[i].scores[i2];
        inFile.ignore(100, '\n');
    }
}

void calcGrade(studentType students[], int numStudents)
{
    double averageScore;

    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        int aggregateScore = 0;
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 5; i2++)
            aggregateScore += students[i].scores[i2];

        averageScore = aggregateScore / 5;
        if (averageScore >= 90)
            students[i].grade = 'A';
        else if (averageScore >= 80)
            students[i].grade = 'B';
        else if (averageScore >= 70)
            students[i].grade = 'C';
        else if (averageScore > 60)
            students[i].grade = 'D';
        else
            students[i].grade = 'F';
    }

}

void print(ofstream& outFile, studentType students[], int numStudents)
{
    outFile << right << "Name" << setw(40) << "Scores" << setw(30) << "Grade" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        outFile << right << students[i].fName << " " << students[i].lName << setw(20);

        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 5; i2++)
            outFile << right << " " << students[i].scores[i2];

        outFile << right << setw(20) << students[i].grade << endl;
    }




}
```

This is what I'm getting in the output file:

```
Name                                  Scores                         Grade
ARCHIE ANDREW                    90 80 70 90 80                   B
BETTY COOPER                    100 100 100 100 100                   A
VERONICA LODGE                    70 70 70 80 80                   C
TARA DREW                    90 80 78 90 89                   B
NANCY COOPER                    100 100 10 90 100                   B
RONI DODGE                    70 77 70 88 80                   C
RICHIE DREW                    90 80 70 90 80                   B
BELLA HOOPER                    100 100 100 100 100                   A
NINA HODGE                    70 70 70 80 80                   C
CLARA DEW                    90 80 78 90 89                   B
FANCY COOP                    100 100 10 90 100                   B
RINA EDGE                    70 77 70 88 80                   C
```

Comment: Notice that Betty's name is one shorter than Archie's and Veronica's is one longer. Where do their grades start relatibve one another? Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I easily format my data table in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765155/how-can-i-easily-format-my-data-table-in-c)

Comment: You can combine first and last name into one string.

Comment: @scohe001 it doesn't seem to. I tried using setfill to help solve the issue, but it did nothing.

Comment: `outFile << students[i].fName << " " << students[i].lName << string(30 - students[i].fName.length() - students[i].lName.length(), ' ');`