# How to center numbers and add list

Tags: c++

i made a program for converting Celcius to Fahrenheit and have some troubles with modifying it. I need to all numeration for each line and center numbers in lines. rn my program outputs all to left. Can you please help me with this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
// Table header
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
system("color F0");
printf("\tTable Output\t");
printf("\n----------------------------------\n");
printf("| Celcius \t | Fahrenheit \t |\n");
printf("----------------------------------\n");

// Table body
for (double i = 15; i <= 30; i++)
{
    printf("| %.f\t\t | %.1f\t\t |\n", i, 1.8 * i + 32);
}

printf("----------------------------------\n");
printf("\n\tList output\n");
using namespace std;
int main();
{
    for (double i = 15; i <= 30; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Celcius: " << i << " --> Fahrenheit: " << 1.8 * i + 32 << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Centering is kinda hard for me..

Comment: Well, assuming you know the number of spaces in your table, you could use something like 'padded output' (refer to `printf` for that, most notably the `% 6.02f` notation) to achieve your centering. (The above would (likely) pad (up to) 6 spaces to the left and stop at 2 digits after the decimal dot).

Comment: @Dopaminos  Check out this below question. One of the answer shows here how you can centrally align your data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765155/how-can-i-easily-format-my-data-table-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already stated in the comments, 'padded output' may be able to help you.
There's some finetuning to be done here, maybe use `sprintf` to get the number of characters and prepend/append spaces accordingly, but here you go with a `C`-Style answer.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
system("color F0");
printf("\tTable Output\t");
printf("\n----------------------------------\n");
printf("|   Celcius  | Fahrenheit |\n");
printf("----------------------------------\n");

// Table body
for (int i = 15; i <= 30; i++)
{
    printf("| % 6d     |   % 6.1f   |\n", i, 1.8 * i + 32);
}
```