# How to create beautiful textual tables in C++?

Tags: c++, text

Is there an easy way to create text tables with +-| characters in c/c++? I'm basically looking for a library. I was almost certain that a library exists and would be easy to find but I didn't find any.

To be more precise, I'm looking for a library to create table like the following:

```
+----+---+
| 1.2|4.2|
+----+---+
|-0.1| .0|
+----+---+
```

Comment: It's not _that_ beautiful

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages questions asking for choices of libraries, since they tend to be subjective and invite some debate. That said, this is an interesting question, and I hope that you find an answer somewhere!

Comment: ncurses is a library that can do this, but I can't say it's simple to use.

Comment: I'm just looking for a practical to do this. It's not like there 10 library and I want to find the best one. My program outputs results of different scientific/computational experiments. It'd be easy to compare in shell like this, otherwise I'll write functions to output html or something ...

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi yeah, you could dump the data into html tables, and view the html page in your browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ and table format printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867122/c-and-table-format-printing)

Comment: just output as cvs format and open it with excel

Comment: I went with the html table and I'm very happy with it.